# if bluetooth is "ON" , location alert dialog is not shown in android at the runtime

Tags: android, bluetooth

In the below code, I am requesting to turn On the location while Bluetooth is turned ON. But the Bluetooth is already ON and still location alert popup is not displayed/shown

Can anyone help me where we did the issue

```
public void requestRuntimePermission(Activity context){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, PERMISSION_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Permission Granted. You can use API which requires the permission." ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context, PERMISSION_LOCATION)){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("This app requires LOCATION permission for particular feature to work as expected.")
                    .setTitle("Permission Required")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{PERMISSION_LOCATION},
                                    PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",(dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss());
            builder.show();

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{PERMISSION_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Granted. You can use API which requires the permission.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context, PERMISSION_LOCATION)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("This feature is unavailabel")
                        .setTitle("Permission required")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", ((dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss()))
                        .setPositiveButton("Settings", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        });
            } else {
                requestRuntimePermission(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `PERMISSION_LOCATION` does not sound like any valid Android permission constant. What is the value of this parameter?

Comment: for requesting location permission

Comment: should I use coarse location instead of fine location?

Comment: I don't know the use-case in your app. You should refer to the Android documentation to decide which one you need.